# Create Quadrants and annotate - seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a seaborn scatterplot with data below. I'd like to create quadrants and annotate each quadrant with what it represents.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"one": [1,2,3,5,6,7,8],
                   "two": [3,6,4,3,8,2,5],
                   "label":['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']})

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='one', y='two', data = df1)

for line in range(0,df1.shape[0]):
    ax.text(df1.one[line]+0.04, 
            df1.two[line], 
            df1.label[line], horizontalalignment='left', 
            size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

Is there a way to do this in seaborn / matplotlib without just adding vertical and horizontal line?

Comment: Use `ax.grid()` to add a grids and `.annotate`. Otherwise the desired result is not clear.

Comment: The horizontal/vertical line addition is probably the simplest but from a data communication perspective, it's not clear why you would want to do that. Typically quads are useful when you need to highlight +/- values for x/y axis. Perhaps rethink just what and how you're trying to commuicate?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add a grid. You can use the `ax.grid` method:

```
ax.grid()
```

[image: axes grid]